# Pressing Win+E takes a very long time as oposed to double clicking My Computer

Tags: windows-xp, shortcuts, dde

I had a similar problem with Microsoft Office files. If I opened Microsoft Word, for example, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> to open a file, it would work instantly. However, if I double clicked on a file, it took a very long time to open. I found this issue somewhere on the forums, saying that this was a DDE problem. I went ahead and fixed it.

However later I also discovered this problem.

If I double click on my computer it starts fine, However, if I use the shortcut keys (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) it takes forever.

Is there a quick fix for this I could try?

Is there a bigger underlying  problem causing this?

Comment: ty for the edits.. looks better now :)

Comment: Could be a function of your keyboard driver.  Is this a laptop?  If so, what make/model?